# How to solve error when installing auto-py-to-exe?

Tags: python, installation, pip, auto-py-to-exe

I am trying to `pip install` **auto-py-to-exe**, but got following error.

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for 
Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

I also
tried to download `wheel` or `.gz file` and install but it gave me the same error.

Here the full error message goes.

```
 C:\Users\soham>pip install C:\Users\soham\Downloads\auto-py-to-exe-2.7.8
Processing c:\users\soham\downloads\auto-py-to-exe-2.7.8
Collecting Eel==0.12.4
  Using cached Eel-0.12.4.tar.gz (15 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller>=3.4 in c:\users\soham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from auto-py-to-exe==2.7.8) (4.0)
Collecting bottle
  Using cached bottle-0.12.18-py3-none-any.whl (89 kB)
Collecting bottle-websocket
  Using cached bottle-websocket-0.2.9.tar.gz (2.0 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\soham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from Eel==0.12.4->auto-py-to-exe==2.7.8) (0.18.2)
Collecting whichcraft
  Using cached whichcraft-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.2 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\soham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller>=3.4->auto-py-to-exe==2.7.8) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in c:\users\soham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller>=3.4->auto-py-to-exe==2.7.8) (0.17)
Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2017.8.1; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\soham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller>=3.4->auto-py-to-exe==2.7.8) (2019.4.18)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\soham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller>=3.4->auto-py-to-exe==2.7.8) (49.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2020.6 in c:\users\soham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller>=3.4->auto-py-to-exe==2.7.8) (2020.9)
Collecting gevent-websocket
  Using cached gevent_websocket-0.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting gevent
  Using cached gevent-20.9.0.tar.gz (5.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\soham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\soham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qcvagi7m\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools >= 40.8.0' wheel 'Cython >= 3.0a5' 'cffi >= 1.12.3 ; platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'greenlet >= 0.4.17 ; platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (27 lines):
  Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
    Using cached setuptools-50.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Collecting Cython>=3.0a5
    Using cached Cython-3.0a6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.0 MB)
  Collecting cffi>=1.12.3
    Using cached cffi-1.14.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (179 kB)
  Collecting greenlet>=0.4.17
    Using cached greenlet-0.4.17.tar.gz (61 kB)
  Collecting pycparser
    Using cached pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for greenlet, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython, pycparser, cffi, greenlet
      Running setup.py install for greenlet: started
      Running setup.py install for greenlet: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\soham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\soham\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gvck6c55\\greenlet\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\soham\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gvck6c55\\greenlet\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0sbse4fp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qcvagi7m\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qcvagi7m\overlay\Include\greenlet'
           cwd: C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gvck6c55\greenlet\
      Complete output (5 lines):
      running install
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'greenlet' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\soham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\soham\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gvck6c55\\greenlet\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\soham\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gvck6c55\\greenlet\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0sbse4fp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qcvagi7m\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qcvagi7m\overlay\Include\greenlet' Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\soham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\soham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qcvagi7m\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools >= 40.8.0' wheel 'Cython >= 3.0a5' 'cffi >= 1.12.3 ; platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'greenlet >= 0.4.17 ; platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0.

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio":
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

You should go on [Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126&fixForIE=.exe.) to install Visual C++ 14.0 without installing Visual Studio.